# Problems with installing Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7

Tags: installation, windows

Despite others, the installation shows "Install alongside Windows 7" option but when I select that option, it asks to remove the installation drive and close the tray if any and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

After I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it restarts and opens Windows and when I put the CD-R again, it goes back to the option. What shall I do?  I don't want to delete any files and Windows 7 but still want to try out Ubuntu 12.04 as I was a former user of Ubuntu 11.04 a year or so ago.

Comment: Are you booting from CD, or running Wubi from it

Comment: I am booting from a CD

Comment: Have you done an [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM/) on the ISO?

Comment: Well i just tried it and it says MD5 check sums are the same

Comment: And does it matter if the windows is a 32-bit and i try to install a 64-bit Ubuntu?

Comment: It's possible to use 64-bit Wubi on a 32-bit copy of Windows, assuming you have 64-bit capable hardware on your machine.  If not you can force Wubi 32bit install, just run Wubi with `--32bit`

Answer (score 1):

How did you get the CD?  Was it: a) Purchased from Canonical, b) Included in a Magazine issue, or c) Downloaded from the website?

If it was downloaded, was it: a) Direct download from Ubuntu.com or b) A torrent download?

I've had issues installing 12.04 from CDs provided in magazines as well as ISOs downloaded via torrent.  So far, I've had the best luck installing from a CD or USB stick created from a direct download disk image.

Others have reported installer issues with 12.04 on specific hardware.  Perhaps try a different source and see if you have the same problem?

Comment: I downloaded it from Ubuntu.com and 11.10 was working perfectly so i don't think that there is a problem with the hardware! thanks i will see

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds as if your Windows 7 is rejecting any attempts to modify the MBR.  In Win7, do you have any malware protection EVER installed, other than the official Microsoft approved software?  There maybe remnants of the other-brand malware protector still on the HDD.

Rather than ordinary Ubuntu, I'd suggest a Rescue Operating System - often Ubuntu-based for greater compatibility for the full range of hardware/ software/ firmware that we all use.  Use that to reset your MBR.

USB sticks are faster than DVD or CDs.  Cheaper in the long run, since easily stored, rugged, water-resistant, tiny, re-used & updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**WUBI**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer).

This may help you install Ubuntu inside Windows and make an entry in the MBR.

When you install Ubuntu through a disk, it makes an entry of available OS in GRUB whereas if you want to play alongside with Windows and Ubuntu, you can try WUBI, which makes an entry in MBR instead of GRUB, hope this helps. Good Luck.